# How to use rust code in a C project while not changing the build system?

Tags: c, rust, automake

I was trying to port nano to rust and using but I don't want to change the build system or nor have two concurrent build system on the same project.

For using rust in a C project I found [this guide](https://rust-embedded.github.io/book/interoperability/rust-with-c.html) but this needs me to either change the build system or use a hybrid approach (i.e. use two build systems at the same time).

Comment: what the problem using cargo in a makefile or whatever ?

Comment: Not sure if _[this will help](https://www.greyblake.com/blog/2017-08-10-exposing-rust-library-to-c/)_.

Comment: What's the problem, specifically? I can understand not wanting to use a hybrid approach but what's the problem with just calling rustc in your Makefile (or whatever)? What have you tried / are you thinking about trying and what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

`rustc` can be called in a similar fashion to `cc` and produce a C-compatible static library. If you're adding only a small bit of Rust that doesn't use Cargo dependencies, this may be easy to integrate into C build systems.

However, by using `rustc` directly you lose access to Cargo, and it'll make use of dependencies as hard and painful as C deps, except Rust programs are used to using hundreds of dependencies.

So the easy way out is to call `cargo build --release` from an existing build system.